# Problems calling function in foreach loop in r

Tags: r, foreach

I'm running 200 simulations, varying one of my six parameters and using just the standard r-setting and a normal for loop. It takes 2 hours pr. variable I vary.

I was recommended running the loop on parallel cores and I found the function foreach and the doSnow library. I've been able to use simple examples posted on different r-blogs and on stack-overflow and ran them on my computer. But so far I've problems with my own written function.

I get the the following error:

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'delta' not found"

Here is a generic code describing the function:

```
  simulation <- function(x){
  #Parameter guesses

  alpha <- x[1]
  mean_ability <-x[2]
  delta <- x[3]
  var <- x[4]      
  lambda_0 <- x[5]
  lambda_1 <- x[6]



HERE THE SIMULATION PART IS DONE


#Put moments together 

c(lam_1_hat,lam_0_hat,delta_hat,mean_within,between_var,average_wage)

}
```

I put this function inside the foreach function:

```
foreach(kk=1:length(alpha_vec), .combine = 'c',.packages=#the packages...) %dopar% {

simulation(c(lambda_1[3],lambda_0[3],delta[3],alpha[kk],var[3],mean_abil[3]))[4]
}
```

So I keep every element fixed except alpha in this case.

During the simulation part I compute random numbers. The set seed command is defined outside the foreach loop. I tried to include it but the error was the same.

I have also tried to include the packages I use, using the .package specification in the foreach-package.

It could make it work by including the whole function code inside the foreach function, but this is surely not the optimal way.

Any suggestions on how to solve my problem?

Comment: Maybe your problem is in the line `simulation(c(lambda_1[3],lambda_0[3],delta[3],alpha[kk],var[3],mean_abil[3]))[4]`. Are you sure that `delta[3]` exists?

Comment: The `delta` vector has 100 entries, so `delta[3]` exist. I can run `simulation` outside the foreach loop without any problems.

Comment: if you replace `foreach` by `for` does it work ok?

Comment: Yes it work if I use `for` instead of `foreach`. But the computing time is quite long.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should include another parameter to your foreach loop, namely .export

Like this:

```
foreach(kk=1:length(alpha_vec), .combine = 'c',.packages=c(the packages), .export= c("simulation")) %dopar% {

simulation(c(lambda_1[3],lambda_0[3],delta[3],alpha[kk],var[3],mean_abil[3]))[4]
}
```